# Django: correctly serialize custom authentication backend

Tags: python, json, django, authentication, serialization

I have a custom authentication backend in Django 1.10. If I login, I get `TypeError: <class 'CustomAuthBackend'> is not JSON serializable`. I can make the entire process work by putting `SESSION_SERIALIZER='django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'` in `settings.py`, but, as pointed out in many old questions, `PickleSerializer` is unsafe and I need a better method.

How do I write a correct serializer for my authentication backend? I tried using some code from https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-oauth2-provider/pull/56/files (adding `serialize()` and `deserialize()` to my authentication backend class and having `serialize_instance()` and `deserialize_instance` as separate functions). I cannot get this approach to work, any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the above suggestions I had were unnecessary (and far too complicated, since the solution I found was much simpler).

I just needed to add the line `user.backend=CustomAuthBackend` in the backend's authenticate method, right before `return user`. Solved all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing that custom authentication and it was running fine, but when trying to  send response as Json it was giving me error for CustomAuthentication is not JSON serialize.

So i added in my settings.py

> SESSION_SERIALIZER='django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'

**Note: I am using Django 1.10 with class based views**

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Change back to as an answer.